# Quarkus liquibase postgres update allocation size sequence

Tags: postgresql, quarkus, liquibase

I'm Trying to update increment by value (allocationSize) of entity using quarkus postgres and liquibase, problem is its throwing error that those values are inconsistent

script I use to update sequence

```
alter sequence ID_SEQ increment by 100;

entity

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "ENTITY")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 100)
    public class ENTITY extends PanacheEntityBase
```

error I'm getting

> Schema-validation: sequence [ID_SEQ] defined inconsistent increment-size; found [1] but expecting [100]

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate fields(ex: id) with `sequenceGenerator` not the Entity
or class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENTITY")
public class ENTITY extends PanacheEntityBase{

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ", allocationSize =100)
public Integer id;

}
```